# The last two digits of the sum of first 'n' natural numbers raised to the power 'n'

Tags: number-theory

What would be the last two digits of the sum of the first 'n' natural numbers raised to the power 'n'?

$$ f(n) = 1^n + 2^n + 3^n + ... + (n-1)^n + n^n $$

For example:
   $$ f(2015) = 1^{2015} + 2^{2015} + 3^{2015} + ... + 2014^{2015} + 2015^{2015} $$

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your title is only the last two digits.  You body is the full sum.  Which is it.  They have very different answers.

Comment: this is somewhat related to bernoulli numbers

Comment: Question's title and body mismatch.

Comment: Oops. My bad. Fixed it now.